# VPN into Cisco/Linksys router

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt

I just recently bought a Linksys EA6200 router and I would like to know if there is any VPN functionality built into the router.

What I'd like to do:
- Connect into a VPN network managed by my router and essentially "be" at home and access my other computers and NASs.
- Not depend on any [server] computer to host the VPN connection through Hamachi, etc.

Is there some PPTP functionality on the router already that would allow me to do the VPN already without any modifications? And how would I set it up?

I saw some firmware like DD-WRT/OpenVPN that might allow this?

I don't understand much of it and would like a little explanation/guidance.

EDIT: I found https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnNPf.png in the config pages of the router, it looks relevant can anyone help configure it.

Comment: You first have to determine your router supports those alternative firmwares.  If it does not or none exist for it then your options are limited.  I am not aware of any Linksys router with VPN support using the default OEM firmware.

Comment: Aww, well it seems like the EA6200 doesn't support DD-WRT either.

Comment: If you can't load custom firmware on the router, and it doesn't support it natively, you're not going to get what you want very easily.

Comment: I found this: http://i.imgur.com/3sWmdM0.png
In the router config panel any ideas if it would work?
I'm not sure how to now connect my computer to it?

Comment: I see no indication the router supports being configured to connect to a VPN. I found the following explaination as what exactly VPN Passthrough means in this context on the Linksys website. **Linksys Wireless-N routers are only capable of enabling the VPN traffic to pass through the device. You will need a VPN router and software to create the actual network to connect with your VPN client. For instructions on how to enable VPN tunnel on a VPN router, click here. To learn how to configure the VPN software, refer to the software’s documentation.**

Comment: OH, so that means that if I have a VPN server behind the router, then the router will allow those connections to passthrough the router's firewall and reach the VPN host, correct?

Seems like I misunderstood what that meant.

Comment: You could pick up a Raspberry PI or some other cheap low power device and make a [VPN Server](http://lifehacker.com/5978098/turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-personal-vpn-for-secure-browsing-anywhere-you-go) on it. Not what you want, but probably the best you can do at this point. Cheaper than buying a new router that supports VPN (or reflashing to DD-WRT)